# Not able to install Marvel puglin on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

Good morning all:

I am trying to install the elasticsearch plugin "Marvel" on Windows 10, I am using the version 5.3.0 of elasticsearch.

When I go the command line, and the go to the "bin directory" of my elasticsearch, I tried all the following commands but none of them works for me, giving different errors:

```
elasticsearch-plugin install license
elasticsearch-plugin install C:\Users\roigm\Downloads\license-2.4.4.zip
elasticsearch-plugin install file://C:\Users\roigm\Downloads\license-2.4.4.zip
```

Please note that I don't have "plugin.bat" but "elasticsearch-plugin.bat"

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: And what are those errors?

Comment: For the first one: "ERROR: Unknown plugin license". Second One: "ERROR: Unknown plugin C:\Users\roigm\Downloads\license-2.4.4.zip" and the for the last command: "Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: C
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)...."

Comment: There is no Marvel in ES 5.3. You need the [XPack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-xpack.html), which includes Monitoring (formerly known as Marvel). And with ES 5.3 only XPack 5.3 works, 2.x anything (Marvel, Shield, license plugin) will not.

Comment: I was able to install the xpack, thanks. I don't see how to mark your response like answered. Can you please this comment to the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Marvel in ES 5.3. You need the [XPack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-xpack.html), which includes Monitoring (formerly known as Marvel). And with ES 5.3 only XPack 5.3 works, 2.x anything (Marvel, Shield, license plugin) will not.